# How to handle ssl certificates for a react app turn-base game and nodejs game server?

Tags: reactjs, websocket, server, https, openssl

In local I was using ws and http to communicate with my server but found out that I needed to switch to wss since using https in dev/prod env.
Website is built using reactjs and server using nodejs.

I self generated openssl the certif and key for the server and input them as args when creating the server :

```
    const server = createServer({
      cert: readFileSync('./sslCertif/server-cert.pem'),
      key: readFileSync('./sslCertif/server-key.pem')
    });
```

I then change ws://... to wss://... in my client but I can't connect and get an error "ServerHandler.ts:15 WebSocket connection to 'wss://...' failed"

Firstly, I'd like to know if this is the right way to do things ? Because I saw people talking about running Apache or docker / kubernates to handle the certificates.

If this is an acceptable way to do things, why doesn't it work ? I saw there can be a cert and key for the client also but couldn't find a way to specify them with native WebSocket js.